# How do I make an on-scren keyboard containint dual fonts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, keyboard

I am making a translating tool for fantasy alphabets. The idea is to have an on-screen keyboard with each button containing each letter in both the Latin alphabet and the alphabet needing to be translated.
The text is then sent into two text fields, typing simultaneousley in both alphabets (one in either textfield), thus being able to translate both into latin letters and into the fantasy font, depending on your translating needs

[image: Concept art.. yikes]

I have the basic HTML all worked out, and I have a number of fonts I want to use for this (attatched through CSS), but the actual functionality eludes me.

I basically want a button press to put the same character into both textareas, and each textarea displays the same text as it is being typed, but in different fonts/alphabets

```
<div ID="keyboard">
  <div id="button-row1">
   <button  class="letter" ID="_a" value="A">
    <span class="latinFont">A</span> | <span class="specialFont">A</span>
   </button>
   <button class="letter" ID="_b" value="B">
    <span class="latinFont">B</span> | <span class="specialFont">B</span>
   </button>
   <button  class="letter" ID="_c" value="C">
    <span class="latinFont">C</span> | <span class="specialFont">C</span>
   </button>
   <button  class="letter" ID="_d" value="D">
    <span class="latinFont">D</span> | <span class="specialFont">D</span>
   </button>
 </div> 

</div>

 <div class="TypedTextFields" ID="TypedTextField">
  <textarea class="LatinTextField" Name="LatinLetters" readonly></textarea>
 <br/>
 <textarea class="SpecialTextField" Name="SpecialLetters" readonly></textarea>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this snippet will help you.

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.letter');
var inputL = document.querySelector('.LatinTextField');
var inputS = document.querySelector('.SpecialTextField');
buttons.forEach(function(button){
  button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    switch(this.value){
      case 'bcsp':
        inputL.value = inputL.value.substring(0, inputL.value.length - 1);
        break;
      case 'enter':
        inputL.value += '\n';
        break;
      default:
        inputL.value += this.value;
    }
    
    inputS.value = inputL.value;
  })
});
```

```css
/****
* Add your latin and special fonts *
****/

.latinFont {
  /* use your latin font-family name */
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
}
.specialFont {
  /* use your spacial font-family name */
  font-family: Impact; 
}
```

```html
<div ID="keyboard">
  <div id="button-row1">
   <button  class="letter" ID="_a" value="A">
    <span class="latinFont">A</span> | <span class="specialFont">A</span>
   </button>
   <button class="letter" ID="_b" value="B">
    <span class="latinFont">B</span> | <span class="specialFont">B</span>
   </button>
   <button  class="letter" ID="_c" value="C">
    <span class="latinFont">C</span> | <span class="specialFont">C</span>
   </button>
   <button  class="letter" ID="_d" value="D">
    <span class="latinFont">D</span> | <span class="specialFont">D</span>
   </button>
   <button  class="letter" ID="_enter" value="enter">
    <span>&lt;-|</span>
   </button>
   <button  class="letter" ID="_bcsp" value="bcsp">
    <span>&lt;-</span>
   </button>
 </div> 

</div>

 <div class="TypedTextFields" ID="TypedTextField">
  <textarea rows="4" class="LatinTextField latinFont" Name="LatinLetters" readonly></textarea>
 <br/>
 <textarea rows="4" class="SpecialTextField specialFont" Name="SpecialLetters" readonly></textarea>
 </div>
```

Comment: This is the exact solution I was hoping to find

but I noticed that I was lacking a special type of button... how do I get the backspace function? it is a string -1, but my feeble attempts has been unfruitful so far

Comment: if(this.id == "_bcksp"){
        inputL.value = inputL.value.substring(0, str.length - 1);
        inputS.value = inputS.value.substring(0, str.length - 1);
      } else {
        inputL.value += this.value;
        inputS.value += this.value;
      }

This is the backspace script as it looks right now - nonfunctioning

Comment: if(this.id == "_bcksp"){ inputL.value = inputL.value.substring(0, inputL.value.length - 1);} else { inputL.value += this.value;} inputS.value = inputL.value;  I refactoring your code. inputS.value is always same as inputL.value

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish this by just using CSS on the textareas.  For example:

```
.LatinTextField {
  font-family: 'Some Font';
}
.SpecialTextField {
  font-family: 'Some Other Font';
}
```

Then in your javascript, you can do the same thing to both textareas, and the CSS does the heavy lifting.  It would also be worth noting that setting a variable globally for each element will help performance because you aren't populating the object each time the function is called.  Here is a basic example:

```
<a onclick="addText('A');">
 <span class="latinFont">A</span> | <span class="specialFont">A</span>
</a>
<textarea id="LatinTextField" Name="LatinLetters" readonly></textarea>
<textarea id="SpecialTextField" Name="LatinLetters" readonly></textarea>

<script>
var latin = document.getElementById('LatinTextField');
var special = document.getElementById('SpecialTextField');
function addText(letter) {
    latin.innerHTML += letter;
    special.innerHTML += letter;
}
</script>
```